# What is the expected timeframe of a double click?

Tags: selection, response-time, mouse, click

In the web application, the user draws a polygonal area on a map each click setting a vertex. A double click allows the user to finish the area. Due to technical circumstances, I have to detect double clicks myself in code.

What time span in milliseconds do users subconsciously expect for a double click? What are the default time spans on desktop applications?

Comment: Please consider touchpad users double tapping, which can get close to a second. Also, mobile users are not that used to double tapping.

Comment: this is a user setting on windows see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978662.aspx (allows for 100ms to 900ms defaults to 500ms)

Comment: The double-click is a so strange and prone to confusion action that almost anything besides computers use them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of double clicking to finish, you could:

- Click the starting point to close the shape (assuming all shapes are closed in)
- Have a button nearby labeled "Finished" or "Close Shape" or "I'm Done" etc. that closes the shape

If you aren't able to use the OS to detect double clicks, I'd avoid them altogether.  I've seen people with disabilities have the double click speed in windows set to the slowest setting and still struggle to do it fast enough.  And double clicking on tablets or touchscreen computers can be quite difficult.

Comment: Yes, this might be a suitable fallback route if double-click as the only option isn't appropriate. Perhaps have the 'Finished' button available anyway *along with the double-click*, which might help cover some bases there. However, one issue I can think of here is that when you're moving your mouse over to the 'Finished' button you'll still be dragging the path with you, which might not feel all that natural to the user.

Comment: There is already a *finished* button, the double click is just an alternative.

Comment: If shape creation is an important/common activity in your app, perhaps allow each user to change the double click speed in the app settings.

Comment: Agree, detecting double click without the OS's help can be irritating for users because the timing may be off what they're used to.  Another option would be shift-click to exit the mode (or control click, etc.).

Comment: How is this an answer for the question?

Comment: @fiatjaf it doesn't exactly answer the "as written" question, but it does answer question implied by the real problem of "how do I close my shapes when I can't detect people double clicking reliably?"

Answer (score 29):

Windows default double-click time is 500 ms (half a second)

Reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760404(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In particular, [DoubleClickTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646258.aspx) can be called to find out what the current time is, and handle the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497.aspx) to check if it's been changed.  (Edit: Nevermind, I missed the "web application" part.)

Answer (score 7):

Great answers here! I'm developing a card game using Python and Pygame, which has no double-click support, so I stumbled upon the same problem.

Inspired on Marcel Böttcher's answer, to measure your own time and then double it, I've created a small tool to measure the speed of double-clicks, and I'm sharing with you:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 48)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

start = None
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT or
            getattr(event, 'key', None) == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if start:
                time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start
                color = (random.randint(0, 255),
                         random.randint(0, 255),
                         random.randint(0, 255))
                screen.fill(color)
                screen.blit(font.render(str(time), True, (255-color[0],
                                                          255-color[1],
                                                          255-color[2])), (0, 0))
                print time
                start = None
            else:
                start = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if start and pygame.time.get_ticks() - start > 900:
            start = None

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

For the record, I tested with my stepfather, who's **71**, very low dexterity (although no disability of any kind)  and *never used a computer / touch / mouse before in his life!*

His results were pretty surprising to me: after a 3 minute training on how to grab and use a mouse (thanks to Solitaire), and what a double click is, he averaged on **250-320 ms** for 30+ tries (mine was 140-180). Even when told the test was *not* about speed (which I guess he assumed to mean "take it easy"), his average was still in the **400-550ms** range.

So I guess 500 is a pretty conservative default, and should handle fine most users. Even 350 would not prevent daddy to enjoy my silly game :)

Comment: Nice post, especially the research with step-dad.

Answer (score 4):

This changes between applications and users, but a typical value is 500ms.

Some people struggle to click fast enough when it's set at 500ms (think people using a touch device), and others find this too slow.  So if you *really* need double click functionality, I would suggest defaulting to 500ms, but offering an option to change it.

I would strongly suggest changing your interaction model so that you **don't use double clicking** at all, as the concept is not at all part of what users of touch devices expect, and often double tapping on touch devices often has a system level meaning (zoom to area for example).

Comment: Alright, what would you suggest as alternative to double click? It's about drawing a polygon on a map. For now, hovering previews the next point, clicking sets the point and double clicking finishes the polygon.

Comment: What about a key modifier? Ctrl + Left Click -> close polygon or something similar

Comment: A key modifier would be even worse on mobile devices.

Comment: An option would be a click with a secondary button, or tap-and-hold. Or if you provide a way to 'undo' the last point, 2nd button brings up a context menu with 'Undo last point', 'Finish shape', and whatever else.

Comment: @danijar I think the most common behaviour is you close the polygon by clicking again on the first point. A-B-C-D-A. If you're talking about lines, you can terminate the line by clicking on the last point: A-B-C-D-D. No need for double clicking anywhere.

Comment: @SteveBennett Alright, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

As it's up to the user to set the double click speed in most operating systems, there aren't any real defaults. I suggest to simple check at which speed it's still comfortably for you to trigger the event and then **double the time span** to hit the speed of a non-professional user.

Comment: How could there not be any defaults? Practically every single OS ever that supported double-click will have had a default value, as opposed to requiring the user to set a value during install, no?

Comment: Every system has its own defaults, yes. But as every system works different, there's no general standard you can build on.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind doubling it for novice users?

Comment: Novice users are less trained in mouse working and have a lower double click rate then experienced users. That's something I always can study when seeing someone's parents first computing attempts.